# egrep to print lines with one and only one t

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, grep

I'm attempting to print lines that have only one t, or only one T, where anything else is fine. IE no lines that have no t's, no lines with 2 or more t's, and no lines that have 1 T and 1 t.

I'm trying :

```
egrep '[tT]{1,1}$' filename
```

and this is showing the following lines:

```
     nopqrstuvwxyz
     letters    (this line is the one that should not be here)
 The price is *$2*
      one two three (this line should not be here either)
    ONE TWO
 THREE
```

These are all the lines that have a t or T in them in the file. How should I be going about this?

Comment: Your attempt does not produce the output you claim. Your regex looks for a *t* at end of line. (Tangentially, specifying exactly one repetition of anything is completely superfluous; your regex could be simplified to just `[Tt]$`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
foobaz
nopqrstuvwxyz
letters
The price is *$2*
one two three
ONE TWO
THREE
1234

$ grep -ix '[^t]*t[^t]*' ip.txt
nopqrstuvwxyz
The price is *$2*
ONE TWO
THREE
```

- `-i` to ignore case
- `-x` to match whole line only

  - by default, `grep` matches anywhere in the line
  - without `-x`, you'd need `grep -i '^[^t]*t[^t]*$'`
- `[^t]*` any character other than `t` (because of `-i` option, `T` would also be not matched)

You can also use `awk` here:

```sh
$ awk -F'[tT]' 'NF==2' ip.txt
nopqrstuvwxyz
The price is *$2*
ONE TWO
THREE
```

- `-F'[tT]'` specify `t` or `T` as field separator
- `NF==2` print if line contains two fields, i.e if the line had one `t` or `T`

Comment: Maybe elaborate that in the absence of `-x`, a match of the regex on a substring anywhere on a line is considered a success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl, below would work

```
> cat ip.txt
foobaz
nopqrstuvwxyz
letters
The price is *$2*
one two three
ONE TWO
THREE
1234
> perl -ne ' $x++ for(/t/ig);print if $x==1 ; $x=0 ' ip.txt
nopqrstuvwxyz
The price is *$2*
ONE TWO
THREE
>
```

If you need to grep with exact 2 matches - just change the condition to $x==2.